# How to get current min and max value in RangeSeekBar in android?

Tags: android, seekbar

I am using RangeSeekBar but i am not able to get updated current min and max value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code

```
// create RangeSeekBar as Integer range between 20 and 75
RangeSeekBar<Integer> seekBar = new RangeSeekBar<Integer>(20, 75, context);
seekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue, Integer maxValue) {
                // handle changed range values
                Log.i(TAG, "User selected new range values: MIN=" + minValue + ", MAX=" + maxValue);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using **RangeSeekBar** Lib.
Use the code below to get the minimum  and maximum values::

```
mSeekBar.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener<Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(
                            RangeSeekBar<?> bar, Integer minValue,
                            Integer maxValue) {
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Min: "+minValue);
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Max: "+maxValue);
                    }
                });
```

Hope this helps :)